# Dynamic Confirmation Message on a confirm.html

Tags: javascript, dynamic, message, window.open, document.write

I am trying to create a Javascript function to display a dynamic confirmation message, that will appear on a confirm.html page. It needs to be in an external Javascript file so that it can be used on a variety of pages. I've tried a variety of things but I just cant quite get it to work correctly. I'm trying to do it with only Javascript.

This is what I have currently, after doing some research

This is button I'm using to call the function

```
<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="dynamicMessage('This product has been deleted')">
```

and the current function I'm using is

```
function dynamicMessage(argument)
{
var test = window.open("./confirm.html","_self");
test.document.write("test");
test.document.close();
}
```

Obviously, the dynamic content isn't added in yet, but if my thinking is correct, it should just be adding the argument somewhere in the long string of html I need to add to create the page. The "test is just do see what happens when calling the function.

What I want it to do is, write the "test" to the new window of confirm.html, but instead it overwrites the current window. But if I only call window.open, it opens to the correct window. It is the document.write part that is throwing me off.

I'm not sure if I'm far off base on my thinking, or if its just a simple mistake I'm missing after hours of looking at this code. Any Ideas?

I think I need to clarify what I am trying to do. I am trying to click a button, in this case a remove button, then open up the page confirm.html, edit the content in confirm.html with the argument, and have the current page now be confirm.html. What currently happens is one of two things either the current document is edited if the "_self" tag is placed, or the html page is open and thus an about_blank url.

Comment: What happens if you don't pass `"_self"` to `window.open()`?

Comment: it opens a new page, but the url is about_blank, where I want it to be confirm.html like it is set in window.open

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understood your question | **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MGgXK/3/)**

Since you are using document.write method it will overwrite contents of your html page

```
function dynamicMessage(argument)
{
var test = window.open("./confirm.html","_blank");
test.document.write(argument);
    setTimeout(function(){test.close()},2000); // after 2 sec it will close
}
```

Comment: after adding the timeout there doesn't really seem to be any change, it still opens up the page in an about_blank page instead of the confirm.html, I've even uped the timeout time to see what that would do, and there is still no change.

Comment: @mr.animenorthview I have edited my solution, it will show your message and redirect to your page, for ex i have taken google http://jsfiddle.net/MGgXK/8/

Comment: what happens now is the page is opened with an about_blank url, then redirected to my page which is now empty. What I want it to do is redirect to my page with the dynamic message on the page.

Comment: @mr.animenorthview If you use document.write then your content will be overridden, so you have to display your msg then redirect, or load your page then using settimeout display your message. And also your code will not run if its cross domain